# Where can I find the APFS format documentation / volume specification?

Tags: macos, ios, filesystem, apfs, documentation

One of my favorite Mac apps, DiskWarrior, [has been waiting for the APFS format documentation](https://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/mojaveapfs.html) (also called the APFS volume specification) for a while, in order to make a new program version which can rebuild APFS disks. Recently, according their page linked above, this documentation was released and Alsoft is using it to update DiskWarrior. I would like to look at this documentation myself, as I find it interesting. However, I can't find the documentation anywhere. I've found a few documents [like this,](https://developer.apple.com/support/downloads/Apple-File-System-Reference.pdf) but I don't think that's what I'm looking for, since that document is not as comprehensive as what I would expect from a full volume format specification.

Do I need a certain Apple subscription to see this documentation or am I simply failing at googling for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think Alsoft's use of the phrase *APFS format documentation* is just that - a phrase they've used rather than referencing an official title.

The [Apple File System Reference](https://developer.apple.com/support/downloads/Apple-File-System-Reference.pdf) is almost certainly what they're referring to. This reference was publicly released on 17 September 2018, and Alsoft made that statement on 4 October 2018.

Prior to the Apple File System Reference, there was no consolidated documentation from Apple regarding APFS - at least not to this level of detail. In fact, the most comprehensive documentation until this was released was actually the result of private academic work in the computer forensics field.

As for Apple itself, we've had the following documentation:

- [Apple File System Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016999-CH1-DontLinkElementID_15) - retired in June 2018
- [About Apple File System](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/file_system/about_apple_file_system) - first published in June 2018, but updated in October 2018 to replace references to HFS+ with HFS Plus instead
- [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH1-SW1) - last updated in April 2018

However, the [Apple File System Reference](https://developer.apple.com/support/downloads/Apple-File-System-Reference.pdf) was last updated in <s>February 2019</s> June 2020.

Comment: I guess I was wrong. I came across that document (as I said above) and I thought it wasn't it, but apparently it is. Thanks for the info and the list of the documentation concerning APFS thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has not yet published full APFS documentation. Only information about reading APFS disks has been released. Missing documentation is about how to write to APFS disks. Until then, DiskWarrior 6 to rebuild APFS disk directory cannot be released.

Check out what Micromat says about it in relation to TechTool Pro:

> **APFS - AGAIN no support**
>
> Providing full support for APFS is entirely dependent on Apple
>   releasing the required documentation for developers. So far, only the
>   documentation explaining the APIs for reading APFS volumes has been
>   released. It is about 140 pages long. We need similar documentation
>   for writing to APFS volumes.

<sup>source: https://www.micromat.com/component/kunena/techtool-pro-11/5225-apfs-again-no-support</sup>

Why? When will it happen? Surprisingly, APFS is still a work in progress. We could say that it is still in beta phase. Hopefully, Apple will announce Time Machine 2 supporting APFS on June 2020 (WWDC). Then, macOS 10.16 with it will be released by end of September 2020. And then Apple will hopefully release really and truly full (sort of) APFS documentation. Then DiskWarrior 6 could be expected in about three to six months testing period. Hopefully.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I find it strange that Micromat is saying this, yet Alsoft is moving forward with their implementation of APFS disk-rebuilding. The documentation available is sufficient for their application, [according to their page.](https://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/mojaveapfs.html) Is it possible that Alsoft has access to some documentation which isn't available to others?

Comment: Only Apple has such documentation, yet it is a moving target and thus not released yet.Prosoft Engineering acknowledges it for Drive Genius: Repartition, and Rebuild utilities are not supported on APFS

Comment: With all due respect, this web form is hard to use. First, I cannot paste all text at once. Second, no way to edit after a few minutes. So, here it goes in several parts. Frustrating!

Comment: Only Apple has such documentation, yet it is a moving target and thus not released yet.

Prosoft Engineering acknowledges it for Drive Genius: “Repartition, and Rebuild utilities are not supported on APFS”.
https://www.prosofteng.com/drive-genius-mac-protection-software
Note that they sayd nothing before, but have now included such sentence.

Comment: Micromat acknowledges it for Techtool Pro, albeit in an indirect way: “Techtool Pro will test, rebuild, and repair damaged directories on corrupted Mac OS Extended hard drives, and optimize the data directories when they are repaired. Techtool Pro can also repair Apple's new APFS file system, standard Mac OS Extended volumes, as well as MS-DOS (FAT32) and ExFAT formatted volumes.
When rebuilding Mac OS Extended volumes, Volume Rebuild will display a comparison chart before directory data is replaced. Use Volume Rebuild to keep your drives operating at their peak performance.”

Comment: https://www.micromat.com/products/techtool-pro
Note that rebuilding directory of APFS disks is not mentioned, albeit it was previously, but not has been deleted.

Comment: Alsoft says that they are working on it with DiskWarrior: “The next major release of DiskWarrior will include the ability to rebuild APFS disks. Apple has recently released the APFS format documentation. Our developers are now using that documentation to update DiskWarrior to be able to safely rebuild APFS disks”.
https://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/mojaveapfs.html

Comment: Yes, as the others will do as well. They said that almost a year ago. Obviously, they do not want to acknowledge that they cannot reach the goal of rebuilding APFS disks without missing Apple documentation. So, until Apple releases such documentation, there is no way.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks a lot for the info! It must be frustrating for these developers, with Apple withholding more documentation for so long... APFS has already been out for several years, what's the hangup? Shouldn't Apple be a little more on the ball? I guess APFS must still be more like a beta product as you said, or perhaps Apple is simply being lazy here.

Comment: Really frustrating for developers. Some of them even quit, like Coriolis Systems:

Comment: OK, here we go. Since comments here cannot be edited after 5 minutes and it took me longer to write this…

Really frustrating for developers. Some of them even quit, like Coriolis Systems:
https://coriolis-systems.com

Apple is withholding documentation about APFS because after several years of releasing it, it still is not finished. Did you notice that Time Machine still requires a 30-year old HFS+ technology to make backups instead of the brand new APFS? Clearly, Apple did not mind to make such development in time.

Comment: In other words, Apple --the richest company on planet Earth with enourmous resources-- is more bussy making emojis or toying with iOS toys instead of devoting required resources to improve macOS (the real computer!) in proper time.

Do not get me wrong. I love Apple and macOS, but this situation is unacceptable for customers that use Macs to work, developers that live from their work and Apple itself as a prestigious corporation! Hopefully, things will change for the better soon. Maybe within this year; most likely next year after WWDC June 2020 as said. Hopefully!!!

Comment: Yes, I've felt the same way many times. Apple needs to devote more attention to things like the filesystem and the kernel, making these things more accessible to developers and power-users who need such access. But sadly you're very right. Hopefully things change indeed!